# How to use the method When in FluentAssertions

Tags: c#, .net, testing, fluent-assertions

Sometimes I have to assert that two lists have the same items. With fluent assertions this can be done like this:

```
class MyObject { public string MyString {get; set;} }

var o1 = new MyObject { MyString = "1    " }
list1.Add(o1);

var o2 = new MyObject { MyString = "1" }
list2.Add(o2);

list1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(list2)
```

But sometimes I want a specific property to be compared in a different way, like this:

```
list1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(list2, options => options
            .Using<string>(context => context.Subject.TrimEnd().Should().Be(context.Expectation))
            .When<string>( ??????? ));
```

I have tried:

```
it => it.SelectedMemberInfo.Name == PropertyNameHere
```

But SelectedMemberInfo can be null and it throws an exception when null and I dont know if I'm calling it the correct way.

Update 1: Tried, but null reference exception:

```
        options => options
        .Using<DateTime>(it => it.Subject.Should().BeCloseTo(DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)))
        .When(it =>
            it != null
            && it.SelectedMemberInfo != null
            && it.SelectedMemberInfo.Name == nameof(Y.X)));
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you specify what is missing in my question? I think it can be understood quite easily

Comment: In this case it's not clear to me `list1` and `list2` are. 

It's easier to help, if you provide a complete example I can copy/paste into an IDE and run.

Comment: Edited question

Answer (score 2):

To match the `MyString` property, the two most used ways are either to match by type or by path.

To match `MyString` by type, you use `WhenTypeIs<string>`.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void MatchByType()
{
    var o1 = new MyObject { MyString = "1    " };
    var list1 = new[] { o1 };

    var o2 = new MyObject { MyString = "1" };
    var list2 = new[] { o2 };

    list1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(list2, opt => opt
        .Using<string>(ctx => ctx.Subject.TrimEnd().Should().Be(ctx.Expectation))
        .WhenTypeIs<string>());
}
```

For the curious `WhenTypeIs<TMemberType>` is simply an alias for

```cs
When(info => info.RuntimeType.IsSameOrInherits(typeof(TMemberType))
```

To match `MyString` by its name, you can use `When(e => e.SelectedMemberPath)`.

`SelectedMemberPath` is defined as

> the full path from the root object until the current object separated by dots.

In this case the root object is `MyObject`, so `SelectedMemberPath` will be `"MyString"`.
So this can be written as:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void MatchByName()
{
    var o1 = new MyObject { MyString = "1    " };
    var list1 = new[] { o1 };

    var o2 = new MyObject { MyString = "1" };
    var list2 = new[] { o2 };

    list1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(list2, opt => opt
        .Using<string>(ctx => ctx.Subject.TrimEnd().Should().Be(ctx.Expectation))
        .When(e => e.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith(nameof(MyObject.MyString))));
}
```

**UPDATE**: `SelectedMemberPath` was renamed to `Path` in [v.6.0.0](https://fluentassertions.com/releases/#600)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to access a member in an object that hasn't been instantiated. Because `it.SelectedMemberInfo` is `null`, there is no member `Name` to access. The .NET documentation on `NullReferenceException` has a good explanation of this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullreferenceexception?view=netcore-3.1

Assuming there are no other special circumstances when `SelectedMemberInfo` is null, you will just want to make the expression in `.When()` null-safe. You can do this pretty easily with a single character (null propagation):

```
it => it.SelectedMemberInfo?.Name == PropertyNameHere
```

The way null propagation works is if the object that precedes the question mark is null, it will evaluate as a null instance of the type at the end of the statement. So in this case, if `it.SelectedMemberInfo` is null, this will evaluate as `(string) null`.

If you like extra lines, you could also do this -

```
it => it.SelectedMemberInfo != null && it.SelectedMemberInfo.Name == PropertyNameHere)
```

If there's a chance that you could have null items in the parent collection, you're also going to want a null check on that -

```
it => it?.SelectedMemberInfo?.Name == PropertyNameHere
```

Comment: Updated question and tried your suggestion but still null reference